# Combining vectors of unequal size using rbind.na

Tags: r

I've imported some data files with an unequal number of columns and was hoping to create a data frame out of them. I've use lapply to convert them into vectors, and now I'm trying to put these vectors into a data frame.

I'm using rbind.na from the package {qpcR} to try out and fill out the remaining elements of each vector with NA so they all become the same size. For some reason the function isn't being recognized by do.call. Can anyone figure out why this is the case?

```
library(plyr)
library(qpcR)

files <- list.files(path = "C:/documents", pattern = "*.txt", full.names = TRUE)

readdata <- function(x)
{
    con <- file(x, open="rt")
    mydata <- readLines(con, warn = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8")
    close(con)
    return(mydata)
}

all.files <- lapply(files, readdata)
combine <- do.call(rbind.na, all.files)
```

If anyone has any potential alternatives they can think of I'm open to that too. I actually tried using a function from [here](http://ryouready.wordpress.com/2009/01/23/r-combining-vectors-or-data-frames-of-unequal-length-into-one-data-frame/) but my output didn't give me any columns.

Here is the error:

```
Error in do.call(rbind.na, all.files) : object 'rbind.na' not found
```

The package has definitely been installed too.

EDIT: changed cbind.na to rbind.na for the error.

Comment: According to the [**docs**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qpcR/qpcR.pdf) there is no exported function under that name in `qpcR`. Either it's not exported or you meant `rbind.fill` from `plyr`.

Comment: Also the error says you are trying to use `cbind.na` rather than `rbind.na`

Comment: interesting. i assumed it was there according to this: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/qpcR/docs/cbind.na. also i didn't think i could use rbind.fill because i'm not using a data frame?

Comment: sorry, i had changed rbind to cbind to see if there would be a difference. my mistake with the error.

Comment: Try using `qpcR:::rbind.na`

Comment: @user1988898 I just checked the source and `rbind.na` *does* exist but as I suspected it is not exported. @James' solution should work.

Comment: @James thank you that worked. question - why does it work? i haven't come across the three colons before but how does that locate the function if, according to Simon, there's no exported function with qpcR?

Comment: I'll write an answer about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the function is not exported by the package. Using `qpcR:::rbind.na` will allow you to access the function.

The triple colon allows you to access the internal variables of a namespace. Be aware though that `?":::"` advises against using it in your code, presumably because objects that aren't exported can't be relied upon in future versions of a package. It suggests contacting the package maintainer to export the object if it is stable and useful.